# Improve speed of MySQL query with 5 left joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

Working on a support ticketing system with not a lot of tickets (~3,000).  To get a summary grid of ticket information, there are five LEFT JOIN statements on custom field table (j25_field_value) containing about 10,000 records.  The query runs too long (~10 seconds) and in cases with a WHERE clause, it runs even longer (up to ~30 seconds or more).

Any suggestions for improving the query to reduce the time to run?

Four tables:

- j25_support_tickets

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `j25_support_tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3868 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  ```
- j25_support_priorities

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `j25_support_priorities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  ```
- j25_support_statuses

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `j25_support_statuses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  ```
- j25_field_value (id, ticket_id, field_id, field_value)

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `j25_support_field_value` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10889 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  ```

Also, ran this:

```
    SELECT LENGTH(field_value) len FROM j25_support_field_value ORDER BY len DESC LIMIT 1
    note:  the result = 38
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id as ID
, (select p.title from j25_support_priorities p where p.id = t.priority_id) as Priority
, (select s.title from j25_support_statuses   s where s.id = t.status_id)   as Status
,     t.subject       as Subject
,     t.email         as SubmittedByEmail
,  type.field_value   AS IssueType
,   ver.field_value   AS Version
, utype.field_value   AS UserType
,  cust.field_value   AS Company
, refno.field_value   AS RefNo
, t.modified_date     as Modified
    FROM j25_support_tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS type  ON t.id = type.ticket_id  AND  type.field_id =1
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS ver   ON t.id = ver.ticket_id   AND   ver.field_id =2
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS utype ON t.id = utype.ticket_id AND utype.field_id =3
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS cust  ON t.id = cust.ticket_id  AND  cust.field_id =4
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS refno ON t.id = refno.ticket_id AND refno.field_id =5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE j25_support_field_value
ADD INDEX (`ticket_id`,`field_id`,`field_value`(50))
```

This index will work as a covering index for your query. It will allow the joins to use only this index to look up the values. It should perform massively faster than without this index, since currently your query would have to read every row in the table to find what matches each combination of `ticket_id` and `field_id`.

I would also suggest converting your tables to InnoDB engine, unless you have a very explicit reason for using MyISAM.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: MySQL gave me an error (error # 1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'field_value' used in key specification without a key length).  ticket_id and field_id are type int(10) and field_value is type tinytext.  Suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, if you are using text columns, this makes the problem much more difficult. Please add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for all tables to your question. Also, add run the following query and report the result `SELECT LENGTH(field_value) len FROM j25_support_field_value ORDER BY len DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Added SHOW CREATE TABLE statements and SELECT LENGTH statement with result per request.  Thanks, Willem.

Comment: @JohnT Sorry for the delay in response, things have been busy. I have updated my answer to include what should now be correct syntax for your table. Try running your query after adding this index, and also try Long Dog's query after adding this index. Then try each again after changing the table type to InnoDB. Make sure to test each query a couple times in each situation to populate the buffer cache, otherwise you may get misleading performance results.

Comment: The `ADD INDEX ('ticket_id','field_id','field_value(50)')` is what solved my problem.  The other SQL tips by @Long Dog were helpful, too, but using adding the index alone changed my response from 30 seconds (or more) to sub-second without touching the query.

Comment: @JohnT Excellent! Glad I could help. Would you consider accepting my answer then since it solved your problem? There should be a way to add a checkmark to my answer, in addition to the ability to upvote (which it appears you/someone did.)

Comment: No, it is _not_ covering.  Prefixing (`x(50)`) prevents it.

Comment: @RickJames The longest length in that column is 38. How is it not covering to index the first 50 characters, especially since empirically it solved his problem? I'm genuinely curious as to why this wouldn't be considered a covering index for his data. Is it a pedantic point, or something more fundamental?

Comment: MySQL does not discover the `38` before deciding on what to do.  It does see the `(50)` and and the `TINYTEXT` and decides that you are not indexing the entire column.  Tomorrow you may insert a 51-character string!

Answer (score 1):

As above - a better index would help.  You could probably then simplify your query into something like this too (join to the table only once):

```
SELECT t.id as ID
, p.title  as Priority
, s.title as Status
,     t.subject       as Subject
,     t.email         as SubmittedByEmail
, case when v.field_id=1 then v.field_value else null end as IssueType
, case when v.field_id=2 then v.field_value else null end as Version
, case when v.field_id=3 then v.field_value else null end as UserType
, case when v.field_id=4 then v.field_value else null end as Company
, case when v.field_id=5 then v.field_value else null end as RefNo
 , t.modified_date     as Modified
    FROM  j25_support_tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value v ON t.id = v.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN j25_support_priorities p ON p.id = t.priority_id
LEFT JOIN j25_support_statuses  s ON s.id = t.status_id;
```

Comment: Definitely better simplified solution with case/when since each ticket can only be of one support field basis..

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with the subqueries for starters and just get them from another join.  You can add an index to j25_support_field_value

```
alter table j25_support_field_value add key(id, field_type);
```

I assume there is an index on id in j25_support_tickets - if not and if they are unique, add a unique index `alter table j25_support_tickets add unique key(id);` If they're not unique, remove the word unique from that statement.

In MySQL, a join usually requires an index on the field(s) that you are using to join on.  This will hold up and produce very reasonable results with huge tables (100m+),  if you follow that rule, you will not go wrong.

are the ids in j25_support_tickets unique? If they are you can do away with the distinct - if not, or if you are getting exact dupicates in each row, still do away with the distinct and add a group by t.id to the end of this:

```
SELECT t.id as ID
, p.title  as Priority
, s.title as Status
,     t.subject       as Subject
,     t.email         as SubmittedByEmail
,  type.field_value   AS IssueType
,   ver.field_value   AS Version
, utype.field_value   AS UserType
,  cust.field_value   AS Company
, refno.field_value   AS RefNo
, t.modified_date     as Modified
    FROM  j25_support_tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS type  ON t.id = type.ticket_id  AND  type.field_id =1
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS ver   ON t.id = ver.ticket_id   AND   ver.field_id =2
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS utype ON t.id = utype.ticket_id AND utype.field_id =3
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS cust  ON t.id = cust.ticket_id  AND  cust.field_id =4
LEFT JOIN j25_support_field_value AS refno ON t.id = refno.ticket_id AND refno.field_id =5
LEFT JOIN j25_support_priorities p ON p.id = t.priority_id
LEFT JOIN j25_support_statuses  s ON s.id = t.status_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did away with the subqueries and altered the tables to add keys.  There was already an index on j25_support_tickets and the id's are unique. Query still runs 27 seconds and the result set is 7,519 records with only 1,896 unique j25_support_tickets (I included the group by id).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

- Switch to InnoDB.
- *After* switching to InnoDB, make the `PRIMARY KEY` for `j25_support_field_value` be `(ticket_id, field_id)` (and get rid if `id`).  (Tacking on `field_value(50)` will hurt, *not* help.)
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`, so don't have both.
- Use `VARCHAR(255)` instead of the nearly-equivalent `TINYTEXT`.
- EAV schema sucks.  [My ran on EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).